# XMLPath Query for nested XML fragment

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to write a xpath query to pull data from an xml document. Unfortunately the document has a xml fragment embedded in it that seems to have lost its encoding (< has become &lt > has become &gt etc).

An example of the xml doc is:

```
<OrderData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Id>1</Id>
    <RawData>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?&gt;
        &lt;Data xmlns="nnn-mmm-com"&gt;
            &lt;Order Action="Remove" &gt;
            &lt;Instrument InstID="1"&gt;&lt;/Order&gt;&lt;
        /Data&gt;
    </RawData>
</OrderData>
```

I'm trying to extract the following values:
Id
Action
InstID

Getting the Id is no problem, but drilling into the fragment inside RawData is proving beyond me. Any pointers gratefully received

(I'm planning to execute the xpath query in Hive using Hive-XML-SerDe which is xpath 1.0)

Thanks

Comment: This cannot be solved with XPath. What environment/programming language do you use? Also, do you have any control over how this document is being created?

Comment: Please Post , how'd you get the value of id ?

Comment: @Tomalak your comment is only true if by "XPath" you mean "XPath 1.0/2.0".

Comment: @MichaelKay I do. So does the OP, see their statement *"I'm planning to execute the xpath query in Hive using Hive-XML-SerDe which is xpath 1.0*".

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: @KrunalShah Xpath for id = "/OrderData/Id/text()"

Comment: @Dan Can you answer my questions from the first comment? You will need to do one step of parsing in an actual programming language. Or you will need to modify how the XML document is produced, it's one or the other.

Comment: @Tomalak, it seems i can do some replace operations (eg swapping the &LT; for < and remove the namespace & xml version tag) & then i can get the data using the hive xpath query i had written. Will pwrite a replace in c#, but it is probably 2-3TB of data, so will also look at writing a pig script to run it on a hadoop cluster. I cant change the XML creation as its historical data from years ago. The joy of data wrangling! Thanks for your response.

Comment: No, don't do any "replace operations", this is an extremely bad idea and it's not going to work reliably. If you have access to C# then you have more than you need to do it properly. You need to do one step of XML parsing. Select `/OrderData/RawData/text()` and parse that into a new XmlDocument. Then run your XPath on that. I'm not sure if a hadoop cluster is necessary for that, but if you want, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 3.1 you can parse the embedded XML document and turn it into a node tree, which you can then process using path expressions. So:

```
/OrderData/RawData/parse-xml(.)/*:Data/*:Instrument/@InstID
```

should get what you want.

You didn't say what version of XPath your library supports, which usually means that it only supports 1.0, so you may need to find a different library.

Comment: Thanks Michael, not sure there is a library for Hive that supports Xpath 3.1, I'll have a look around